# DataFrameSelector in sklearn_features.transformers

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is the DataFrameSelector in sklearn_features.transformers the only one? Or are there more?

I am getting the following error on running the following code in the Jupyter notebook.-

> from sklearn_features.transformers import DataFrameSelector
>
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 from sklearn_features.transformers import DataFrameSelector
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install it before importing. It is not present in your python path

Try in a cell before the following command:

```
!pip install sklearn_features
```

and then

```
from sklearn_features.transformers import DataFrameSelector
```

Example from colab
[image: from colab]